# XML: How to delete nodes with <x elements, but keep the ones with >x elements

Tags: c#, xml

I have a small problem here regarding XML files. I am writing a program that reads an XML Document and processes the information for other purposes.

I am still writing the reading part. Reading the XML is not very hard but unfortunately, the program that creates these XML files has some flaws. It sometimes creates Nodes which only contain the subnode "Count1" but nothing else. The subnode is empty as well.

I wrote a routine that would go through all the nodes and count the number of subnodes and elements so I could figure out which nodes were empty and deleted them.

Problem is, that sometimes the (nearly) empty nodes have the same name as a not empty node. in this case it deletes wrong nodes with information in it.

So what I need is a way to find out how many elements are in that node before deleting it. I can easily find a node that fits a name with `.SelectSingleNode()` but it only finds the first element with that name and I can't switch to the next one.

Do you have any idea how to iterate through the nodes of one name and delete only the ones I want?

Comment: Post a piece of your code/logic

Comment: You could use a LINQ `where clause` and skip over any node that has an empty subnode.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `.SelectNodes()` instead of `.SelectSingleNode()` so you can iterate through all nodes returned and check for whatever condition of each node and take action accordingly.

There maybe a different suggestion that better fit you situation if you could post concise sample of the XML and relevant portion of C# code you have (I guess checking for *empty nodes* as you said can be done solely in XPath).